# Updating only part of an HTML page using Django

Tags: django, ajax

I have an HTML (annotator.html) page where the top half contains a table. I have JavaScript code that pulls data out of the data model when the user selects a row in the table and displays that data in a div below the table.

My Javascript looks like this:

```
$('#radiological tbody').on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
    if ( $(this).hasClass('selected') ) {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
    }
    else {
        //first unselect any other selected row
        dt_table.$('tr.selected').removeClass('selected');

        //then select row of interest
        $(this).addClass('selected');

        var rowIndex = dt_table.row('.selected')[0];
        var row = dt_table.rows(rowIndex);
        var id = row.data()[0]['id'];
        var url = '/report/' + id + '/';
        //window.location = url;

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'get', // This is the default though, you don't actually need to always mention it
            success: function(data) {
            },
            failure: function(data) {
                alert('Got an error dude');
            }
        });
```

And correctly populates the bottom half of my page but also updates the top half.  I Just want the bottom half refreshed.

My report view looks like this:

```
def report_page(request, id):   
    template_name = "annotator.html"
    data = Radiology2.objects.get(id=id)
    context = {"data": data}
    context["title"] = title
    context["version"] = version
    context["id"] = id

    if (request.is_ajax()):
        # return render(request, template_name, context)
        return JsonResponse(context)
    else:
        return render(request, template_name, context)
```

I added support for AJAX.  I'm  just not sure how to return from view properly when AJAX is used.  Obviously, I'm not understanding something.

Comment: Yes, this needs to be done using ajax. There are loads of resources if you search for "django + ajax" that will put you on the right track. Please research first and try it before asking.

Comment: I did research before asking but did not make any progress until just now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of Ajax, I replaced `window.location=url;` with `$('#divIdToRefresh').load(url +  ' #divIdToRefresh');`

Answer (score -1):

You can easily use Ajax - jQuery or native JS would be better for that

Comment: This doesn't solve any problem, you should have commented your idea.

Comment: Would you please share an example?